# Cyclic Dependency when using RelationshipEntity

Tags: maven, neo4j, relationship, spring-data-neo4j-4

Let's say, i have an `User` and a `Product`.
The user should be able to rate products and a rating can have a lot of properties like for example a number of stars from 1 to 5.
I'd like to have the `Product` and the `User` in different Maven modules.
However, `Product` should know its Owner, so there is a dependency to the module, holding `User`.
I also would like to have a Rating-Module that contains everything related to ratings.

I constructed the Rating

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="RATES")
public class Rating{
  private Long id;
  @StartNode
  private User rater;
  @EndNode
  private Product ratee;
  @Property
  private RatingProperty property;
  //Getter/Setter
}
```

Where the `RatingProperty` contains the `int` representing the 1 to 5 star rating.
Now I understand from the [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/) that I need to have the `Rating` as an attribute inside some node because SDN4 doesn't accept it otherwise.
Indeed when i did not use it as an attribute and tried `save` it, i got the id `null` and not element appeared in the DB.
Since the `Rating` needs to know both `User` and `Product`, I get a cyclic dependency when I try to put the `Rating` into the `User` class.
The same when i put it into the `Product` Class.

As far as I understand at the moment, using a `RelationshipEntity` seems to not be possible when the Start- and EndNode entities are in different Maven Modules, because the Relationship needs to know both and one of the nodes needs to know the relationship.
This doesn't seem right, so I think I understand something very wrong.
I also tried creating a new NodeEntity inside the Rating-Module just to hold the `Rating`. This was

```
@NodeEntity
public class RatingWrapper{
  private Long id;
  @Relationship(type="RATES)
  private Rating rating;
  //Getter/Setter
}
```

but this way i got the same behavior that i did when i didn't use the `RelationshipEntity` as an attribute somewhere.

Do you see a way to do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing Vinces advice, I changed the progress of creating the relationship. Unitl now, i persisted the startnode, then the endnode and then tried to use a repository `extends GraphRepository<Rating>` to `save` the RelationshipEntity. Whenever I did this, i got a rating with id `null`. When I added the rating as an attribute to the startnode and instead of saving the new relationship, saved the startnode, it worked.
I'm not sure, if this is the proposed way, but I got my relationship, so it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

A RelationshipEntity represents an edge with in the graph on which you can set and retrieve properties via your domain objects. However, because Neo4j does not support hyper-edges (edges attached to other edges), those properties must be simple Java properties, not other objects in your domain like `RatingProperty`.

Try replacing `RatingProperty` with a simple `Integer` first and see if that solves your problem. If so, you can then use a [Custom Converter](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/#reference_programming-model_conversion) to convert between the Integer property rating in the graph and your RatingProperty object.

If your domain objects are in different modules this should not cause any problems: just ensure that all of the relevant packages are enumerated in the argument to the SessionFactory constructor:

`new SessionFactory("app.module1.domain", "app.module2.domain", ...)`

Comment: This did not solve my problem, since my `RatingProperty` is currently just an enum, but this probably would have resulted in future problems, thank you.